# How to quickly create a grid of histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(17,17))
axes =  axes.flatten()
labels = ['d','f']
l1 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[0],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='a', data=dff_2k)
l2 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[1],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='b', data=dff_2k)
l3 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[2],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='c', data=dff_2k)
l4 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[3],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='d', data=dff_2k)
l5 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[4],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='e', data=dff_2k)
l6 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[5],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='f', data=dff_2k)
l7 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[6],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='g', data=dff_2k)
l8 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[7],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='h', data=dff_2k)
l9 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[8],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='i', data=dff_2k)
l10 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[9],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='j', data=dff_2k)
l11 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[10],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='k', data=dff_2k)
l12 = sns.histplot(ax=axes[11],hue=dff_2k['source'],x='l', data=dff_2k)
fig.legend([l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12],labels=labels,loc='upper right')
axes[0].get_legend().remove()
axes[1].get_legend().remove()
axes[2].get_legend().remove()
axes[3].get_legend().remove()
axes[4].get_legend().remove()
axes[5].get_legend().remove()
axes[6].get_legend().remove()
axes[7].get_legend().remove()
axes[8].get_legend().remove()
axes[9].get_legend().remove()
axes[10].get_legend().remove()
axes[11].get_legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

How can I minimize this code? I just want to add only features and then axis to create the different subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) can create this kind of plot in one go. As `displot` creates its own figure and subplots also that step should be omitted. Most seaborn functions work best for data in ['long form'](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data). Panda's `melt()` converts dataframes from wide to long form.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first create some test data similar to the question
dff_2k = pd.DataFrame({colname: np.random.randn(2000).cumsum() for colname in 'abcdefghijkl'})
dff_2k['source'] = np.repeat([*'df'], len(dff_2k) // 2)
# transform the dataframe to long form
dff_2k_long = dff_2k.melt(id_vars='source', var_name='col name', value_name='value')
# plot everything in one go
g = sns.displot(data=dff_2k_long, kind='hist', x='value', hue='source',
                col='col name', col_wrap=4, height=3, aspect=1.5,
                common_bins=False, facet_kws={'sharex': False})
g.set(xlabel='')  # remove the x-axis labels
plt.show()
```

[image: grid of sns.histplots]

PS: To change the subplot titles you can use:

```py
for label, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
     ax.set_title(label)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @JohanC . how to remove the **col name=** on x-axis.

Comment: See updated answer.